# Nonnegative linear recurrent sequence plus roots with modulus $>1$ implies goes to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Let $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ be a nonzero sequence of nonnegative real  numbers satisfying a linear recurrence with constant coefficients :

$$
u_{n+r}=\sum_{j=0}^{r-1} a_ju_{n+j} \ (n\in {\mathbb Z})
$$
(so $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{r-1}$ are fixed real constants)

If all the roots of the characteristic polynomial $X^r-\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}a_jX^j$ have modulus $>1$ (in particular $(u_n)$ cannot be periodic), does it automatically follow that $u_n \to +\infty$ when $n\to +\infty$ ?

The difficulty comes of course from the cases where there are several roots sharing the
maximum modulus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not follow.  For example
$$u_n=2^n+(-2)^n$$
has characteristic equation with roots $2$ and $-2$; however $u_n=0$ whenever $n$ is odd, so $u_n$ does not tend to $\infty$.